# How to Codable firebase timestamp in ios swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I am trying to do decode the firebase collection with `FirebaseDecoder()`. Here is the model i used

**Method 1**

```
struct firebaseApplication:Codable {

var uid:String?
var status:String?
var jobId:String?
var companyId:String?
var createdDate: Timestamp? // or  //    Date? // or // String?

}
```

if i comment the **createdDate** then result is getting. Otherwise no result. I tried giving **createdDate** as `Timestamp?` and `Date?` and `string?`, All cases no result.

i tried the another way it is working fine, here it is

**Method 2**

```
struct ApplicationCollection:CustomStringConvertible {
var description: String
var uid: String
var status:String
var jobId:String
var companyId:String
var createdDate:Date

init(Dict:[String:Any]) {

    self.uid = Dict["uid"] as? String ?? ""
    self.status = Dict["status"] as? String ?? ""
    self.jobId = Dict["jobId"] as? String ?? ""
    self.companyId = Dict["companyId"] as? String ?? ""
    let str = Dict["createdDate"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
    self.createdDate = str.dateValue()
    self.description = "[uid: \(uid),status: \(status),jobId: \(jobId),companyId: \(companyId),createdDate: \(createdDate)]"

}

init?(data: Data) {
    guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
    self.init(Dict: json)
}
init?(json: String) {
    self.init(data: Data(json.utf8))
}
}
```

**Method 2** is working fine getting all data along with **createDate**

why in **Method 1** case not getting **createDate** ?. Did i missed anything?.

**How to solve it**

Comment: what do you mean by how to codable?

Comment: Hey @chandra1234, I'm also facing the same issue, Please let me know if you have already solved the above problem. Thanks!

Comment: @thevikasnayak I given below answer for above problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found a solution to my question.

I was mistaken, while decoding `Timestamp()` we have to use `FirestoreDecoder()` instead of `FirebaseDecoder`.

Here it is i changed from firebase To firestore

```
let decoder = FirebaseDecoder()
                let data = try decoder.decode(firebaseApplicationCollection.self, from: i.data())
```

instead of

```
let decoder = FirestoreDecoder()
                let item = try decoder.decode(firebaseApplicationCollection.self, from: i.data())
```

I hope this answer will help others to identify exact problem while decoding the `Timestamp` in firebase

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase project to save me lots of code around this sort of stuff. It's really helped with dealing with FireStore and it also handles Timestamps.

Comment: i'm also using same one. i mentioned above "FirebaseDecoder()" you can see

Comment: @drekka is it possible to put any example with Timestamp. I am also trying same

Answer (score 0):

Looks like method 2 is working because you are manually mapping the variables with the key/value pairs.

Method 1 may not be working because you are trying to map a string to a custom type (not sure if TimeStamp is encodable or not, as implementation is not provided) instead of the raw string it is. Perhaps set the created date as a string in method one, and create an accessor() for the date object of that string.

Method 2 is seems that you know it is a string, but set the createdDate to the `dateValue` of the that timestamp, as the types are aligning.

Can you post your implementation of Timestamp for review?

Comment: i tried that part also set createdDate as  a String still no response.
even i'm not getting any result, it is moving to catch block. what is the use of implementation of timestamp. Model is not accepting the decoder.

Comment: in Method2 also i given exact data type i.e as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()

Comment: @chandra1234 is Apple support this library? https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase